# Time Stamp in java using formatter

Tags: java, date, timestamp

How to create a timestamp in Java in the following format:

```
Day Date Year Hour:Minutes:Seconds:MillieSeconds GMT
```

I tried with `Date` for matter but was not possible.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and explain us what makes it impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` class. I will not write exact code for educational reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar class. Or better still - the Joda-Time API.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/